# Rails: get image source after asset precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I do this for my website

```
image_tag("logo.png")
```

This results

```
<img src="/assets/logo-c9dc9867ad75fdidmjdoehdo53di.png" alt="Logo" />
```

This works just fine for me. But sometimes I just need the source part of the image i.e I just need this part `/assets/logo-c9dc9867ad75fdidmjdoehdo53di.png`. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images are in `app/assets/images`, then use [*`asset_path`*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/asset_path)

```
<%= asset_path("logo.png") %>
# => "/assets/logo-c9dc9867ad75fdidmjdoehdo53di.png"
```

If your images are in `public/assets`, then use [*`image_path`*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path)

```
<%= image_path("logo.png") %>
# => "/assets/logo-c9dc9867ad75fdidmjdoehdo53di.png"
```